# How to use previous quarter's data when quarter is missing from dataset

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to write a SQL query in Presto for a cumulative delivery forecast. However, there aren't always deliveries every quarter, so for a quarter with no deliveries, there is no row at all for that quarter's data. I would like to use the previous quarter's data when this happens.

I have tried creating a CTE with all the quarters I want populated and using some window functioning to fill in the missing data. I was trying to use a CASE statement for if null, then LAG(quarter - 1) but the CASE statement in general seemed not to work.

```
with forecasts as (
    select quarter, type, location, sum(total)
    from delivery_db
    group by 1,2,3
)

quarters AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('2024-Q1'),
            ('2024-Q2'),
            ('2024-Q3'),
            ('2024-Q4')
    ) v(quarter)
)

SELECT
    q.quarter,
    f.type,
    f.location,
    --CASE(WHEN f.quarter is not null then SUM(total) else LAG(f.quarter, 1))
    SUM(total) OVER(
        PARTITION BY
            f.type
        ORDER BY
            q.quarter
    ) AS total
FROM quarters q
FULL JOIN forecasts f
on f.quarter = q.quarter
```

DeliveryDB looks like:

| Quarter | Type | Location | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeA | TBD | 10 |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeA | TBD | 4 |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeA | TBD | 5 |

Actual

| Quarter | Type | Location | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeA | TBD | 14 |
| 2024-Q2 | null | null | null |
| 2024-Q3 | null | null | null |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeA | TBD | 19 |

Desired

| Quarter | Type | Location | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeA | TBD | 14 |
| 2024-Q2 | TypeA | TBD | 14 |
| 2024-Q3 | TypeA | TBD | 14 |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeA | TBD | 19 |

Comment: Where is in query cte ``forecasts`` or table ``delivery_db`` ?

Comment: `delivery_db` is the primary table, `forecasts` was a way to aggregate the deliveries by quarter.

Comment: You do not use delivery_db in your query. Or I didn't see it, I missed it?

Comment: It's in the CTE for `forecasts`

Comment: Please forgive me for being incomprehensible, bat query is ``select ... from quarters``. I was expecting something like``select ... from  quarters left join forecasts on ...``

Comment: Oh I see my mistake now, I missed the JOIN when copying/pasting. Yes, `quarters` is joined to `forecasts`, sorry for the confusion! I updated the query to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example.

1. First, we create a framework for the result - All quarters X (All Types and Locations)
2. Then join calculated sums by (quarter,type,location) and sum rolling total

```
with forecasts as (
  select quarter, type, location, sum(total) total
    from delivery_db
    group by quarter, type, location
)
,quarters AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('2024-Q1'),
            ('2024-Q2'),
            ('2024-Q3'),
            ('2024-Q4')
    ) v(quarter)
)
,AllPoints as(
   select * 
   from quarters,
    (select distinct type,location from forecasts)f
)
SELECT
    q.quarter,
    q.type,
    q.location,
    SUM(case when f.quarter=q.quarter then total else 0 end) 
       OVER(PARTITION BY q.type,q.location ORDER BY q.quarter
     ) AS total2,
     f.quarter,
     f.total qtl_total
FROM AllPoints q
left join forecasts f on q.quarter= f.quarter
    and q.type=f.type and q.location=f.location
order by type,location,q.quarter
```

Output

| quarter | type | location | total | quarter | qtl_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeA | TBD | 14 | 2024-Q1 | 14 |
| 2024-Q2 | TypeA | TBD | 14 | null | null |
| 2024-Q3 | TypeA | TBD | 14 | null | null |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeA | TBD | 19 | 2024-Q4 | 5 |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeB | TBD | 7 | 2024-Q1 | 7 |
| 2024-Q2 | TypeB | TBD | 7 | null | null |
| 2024-Q3 | TypeB | TBD | 15 | 2024-Q3 | 8 |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeB | TBD | 15 | null | null |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeB | TBL | 0 | null | null |
| 2024-Q2 | TypeB | TBL | 0 | null | null |
| 2024-Q3 | TypeB | TBL | 3 | 2024-Q3 | 3 |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeB | TBL | 3 | null | null |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeB | TBX | 33 | 2024-Q1 | 33 |
| 2024-Q2 | TypeB | TBX | 33 | null | null |
| 2024-Q3 | TypeB | TBX | 33 | null | null |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeB | TBX | 33 | null | null |
| 2024-Q1 | TypeB | TBY | 0 | null | null |
| 2024-Q2 | TypeB | TBY | 0 | null | null |
| 2024-Q3 | TypeB | TBY | 0 | null | null |
| 2024-Q4 | TypeB | TBY | 51 | 2024-Q4 | 51 |

With test data

```
insert into delivery_db values
 ('2024-Q1','TypeA','TBD',  10) -- 1,4 quarters 
,('2024-Q1','TypeA','TBD',  4)  -- 
,('2024-Q4','TypeA','TBD',  5)  --
,('2024-Q1','TypeB','TBD',  7)  -- 1,3 
,('2024-Q3','TypeB','TBD',  8)  --
,('2024-Q3','TypeB','TBL',  3)  -- only 3 q
,('2024-Q1','TypeB','TBX',  33) -- only 1 q
,('2024-Q4','TypeB','TBY',  51) -- only 4 q
;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nLN8yS_d)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much for the help and quick turnaround! The AllPoints table and the ability to do a case within the SUM were the two pieces I was missing.